# HTML5 canvas multiplayer game with node.js and Isogenic engine

Tags: multiplayer, rpg, databases, node.js

I want to create a multiplayer game using [Isogenic engine](http://www.isogenicengine.com/) i understand that this technology uses html5 and canvas for rendering graphics in frontend and node.js for backend. I started working on how the game should work and what i need to accomplish what i want. I understand that node.js goes well with noSQL dbs. My question is what should i use SQL or noSQL for the game?

Game will be multiplayer RPG with heavy accent on chatting feature, so i have many thing to store. But i cant figure out which one should i choose. What would be benefits of choosing eather? Maybe i should think about other solution? Any tips would be much appreciated. :)

EDIT: What i actually meant was, can mongoDB store user personal data, like passwords, emails. Is there security issues? Because i know node.js is not the best for communicating with relation databases.

Comment: Welcome to gamedev.stackexchange.com. Unfortunately, "which technology to use" quesitions are considered off-topic here, because they are always discussion-oriented. I would recommend you to learn both technologies so you know what their main differences are and then make an educated decision which is better for **you** and **your specific project**. Also, [there is no such thing as NoSQL](http://ontraindevelopment.blogspot.de/2013/07/there-is-no-such-thing-as-nosql.html). Each of the databases grouped under that umbrella term is completely different and deserves to be evaluated separately.

Comment: Actually what i meant was mongoDB, and can i use both for storing everything?

Comment: You *can*. But whether or not you *should* depends on *you* and on *your specific project*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answer to the more clarified question in your edit)

MongoDB is perfectly suitable for storing user data, such as emails and passwords. As long as you are taking all the same precautions you'd use for an SQL database (hashing passwords and such,) there should be no additional security issues.

Comment: Well, then again *anything* is perfectly suitable for storing anything if you take appropriate security precautions. (*Encrypt all the things!*) MongoDB might be unadvisable for certain purposes of user data storage for [other reasons](http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2013/11/11/why-you-should-never-use-mongodb/) though.